# What's the result of multiplying a rotation matrix having only ψ components by another which has (−φ,θ,−ψ) components?

Tags: rotation

Given the following rotation matrix:

$  
     R(φ, θ, ψ) =   \left( \begin{smallmatrix}
        cos(θ)*cos(ψ) &  -sin(φ)*sin(θ)*cos(ψ)-cos(φ)*sin(ψ) &  -cos(φ)*sin(θ)*cos(ψ)+sin(φ)*sin(ψ) \\
        cos(θ)*sin(ψ) &  -sin(φ)*sin(θ)*sin(ψ)+cos(φ)*cos(ψ) &  -cos(φ)*sin(θ)*sin(ψ)-sin(φ)*cos(ψ) \\
               sin(θ) &                        sin(φ)*cos(θ) &                        cos(φ)*cos(θ)
    \end{smallmatrix}  \right)
$

The multiplication $ R(0, 0, ψ)^T * \begin{pmatrix}ẋ& ẏ& ż\end{pmatrix}^T $ returns new linear velocities:
\begin{pmatrix}ẋ_n& ẏ_n& ż\end{pmatrix}
Which account for the effect of yaw on $ ẋ $ and $ ẏ $, because only the components of $ ψ $ remain in $ R $ and since $ ψ $ is around $ Z $, its components are in $ X $ and $ Y $.

Now my question is, what does the following multiplication return: $ R(0, 0, ψ)^T * R(-φ, θ, -ψ)^T $ ? and what does it account for?

Comment: Are you sure that you got the signs correct in the entries (1,2), (2,1), (2,3) and (3,2)? The rotation matrix R looks very similar to a Euler XYZ angles, but it additionally flips the y axis before and after the rotation.

Comment: I ported it directly from [CoppeliaSim](https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/), and the multiplication is part of a working control flow for a quadcopter.

Comment: $ R(-φ, θ, -ψ) $ is basically like multiplying entries (1,2), (2,1), (2,3) and (3,2) by -1. However, what I don't understand is what the final multiplication represents, what it accounts for.